# Reduce writes from a specific application?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, cache, ramdisk

I'm logging the output of a command with

```
command | tee file
```

This causes `tee` to *actually* write to the disk every second or so. I'd like to reduce the frequency of the writes, by caching the output more.

I know this can be done at the system level, for all processes, but is there a *simple* way to do this at the user level, just for this process?

(Having `tee` write to `ramdisk` and then having another process periodically copy the output; or modifying `tee` itself seem overly complicated)

Comment: I don't understand why you accepted an answer that you said did not help you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it answered it in general, and if my particular case cannot be addressed (easily), that's useful to know. If there are better answers that prove this wrong, I'll change the "accept" vote.

Comment: You could leave the question without an unaccepted answer to encourage more people to come along and post competing answers. You don't need to accept an answer right away.

Comment: One write per second is not a heavy load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
command | stdbuf -o5M cut -b-
```

For 5MiB output buffering. See `man stdbuf` for a list of options. Note this doesn't work with `tee` which overrides the the buffer modes.

Comment: Thanks, but if this doesn't work with tee, how does this help me?

Comment: If you want to log the output of a command, redirect stdout to a file you want to log it to.

Comment: I want to get both stdout and the log file (hence `tee`)

Comment: Well, I checked and `cat` also doesnt work. I suppose `cut` will. I edited the command. `tee` is not designed to work this way, so pick your poison.